# How to set teamcity to run android tests for every build

Tags: android, gradle, teamcity

I have the following tests in project/src/java/test.project.example/*. When i commit some file to repository teamcity check this and build apk file. So i want that teamcity run all tests from project/src/java/test.project.example/* too. How i can do it? 
Examples of tests:

```
public class ContentIdsParserTest extends AndroidTestCase {
  public void testParser() {
    assert(somethingExp,somethingReal);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When specifying which gradle tasks to run in your CI configuration, add `testRelease` (or `testDebug` or whatever particular build variant you want) to the list of tasks. This will run the unit tests. See the Android [unit test documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) for more details.